# How to display output from html elements in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I have the following array in my `main.js`.

```
ko.observableArray(
    [ output[0],output[1],output[2],output[3],output[4]]);
```

and I want to dislpay each `output[i]` one by one on the ul element of the following html:

```
<section>
    <ul id="results" ></ul>
</section>
```

How to achieve it ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: And you have tried... what, exactly?

Comment: @Tomalak yes have tried the for each binding, but could not successfully achieve it.

Comment: Then show your code. (Besides: What you want is *extremely* basic. It's the bread and butter of knockout. The Knockout documentation covers it. The knockout live tutorial covers it. Thousands of threads on Stack Overflow cover it. "I gave up after one attempt" does not cut it. Try harder.)

Answer (score 2):

maybe you should work through the getting started interactive tutorial.  http://learn.knockoutjs.com/

```js
function viewModel(output) {
  this.myArray = ko.observableArray(
    [output[0], output[1], output[2], output[3], output[4]]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>


<section>
  <ul id="results" data-bind="foreach: myArray">
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Also, it would be better to simply assign the observable array this way: `this.myArray = ko.observableArray(output);`